# Is my Corsair DDR4 memory (CMK16GX4M4B3000C15) affected by RowHammer?

Tags: memory, security

I have a *Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (4 x 4GB) DDR4 DRAM 3000MHz (PC4-24000) C15 memory kit for DDR4 Systems (CMK16GX4M4B3000C15)*.

I can't seem to find out whether it is affected by the Rowhammer vulnerability or not. I contacted Corsair and they simply said there was not even a way to know what chip is in these modules.

How can I find out if this chipset is affected, or generally, how to check this for similar memory chips (4x4gbs, 3000mhz, etc.)

Comment: Asking for lists is not usually considered a 'good question' on SE sites. I have edited your question

Comment: You can test if your RAM is vulnerable though [this tool](https://github.com/google/rowhammer-test) created by Google. Asking for hardware recommendations is also off-topic.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135699/how-to-detect-rowhammer-vulnerability

Answer (score 1):

[Row hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer)
can be mitigated by the chipset, although some memory producers have inbuilt
protections into the memory chips themselves.

[Cisco has published](https://blogs.cisco.com/security/mitigations-available-for-the-dram-row-hammer-vulnerability)
some useful information on how to mitigate the Row Hammer issue. In that blog entry, Cisco reports that Intel’s Ivy Bridge, Haswell, and Broadwell server chipsets support Target Row Refresh capability, therefore are likely not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Following the links posted revealed that a field called Maximum Activation Count in the RAM SPD will be 'unlimited' if it is rowhammer safe. I found a tool called RamMon from passmark that displays the info, and this set of RAM displays 'unlimited' for MAC SPD field so it should be safe.